# XAMPP Server has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: php, html, ajax

Hello I have been dealing with this problem since 10 am, about 10 hours have passed but still could not fix the problem. I am constantly trying to fix this problem.

```
Problem Image / https://i.hizliresim.com/AtfbH9.png
The methods I'm trying to solve / https://i.hizliresim.com/SpWBzn.png)
The methods I'm trying to solve / https://i.hizliresim.com/ioZr55.png)
```

i am using XAMPP. Please help me with this. I'm having a nervous breakdown. I'll go crazy soon.

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular the part about not posting pictures of text.

Comment: We're programmers, we can read. Please read about [why you shouldn’t upload images of code or errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

You are limiting your resource access to only `http://mabbo.biz/` but accessing the resource from `https://mabbo.biz/`, the two schemes don't match hence the CORS error, `http` and `https` are different.

Also, your wildcard `*` is being overwritten by your explicit one, or as MDN puts it.

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin specifies either a single origin, which tells browsers to allow that origin to access the resource; or else — for requests without credentials — the "*" wildcard, to tell browsers to allow any origin to access the resource.

So since you have the `http://mabbo.biz/` origin specified, any other origin will be rejected.

You could add a check to allow wildcard's on specific URLs or specific resource types, like `.jpg|.png|.gif`.

How that will be accomplished will differ from server to server though, so you'll have to look up how your server handles that check.

Comment: Could you please share your Discord account